# Creating a cumulative sum column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Sample table ID: (num is a key so there wouldn't be any duplicates)

```
num
1
5
6
8
2
3
```

Desired output:
(Should be sorted and have a cumulative sum column)

```
num cumulative
1    1
2    3
3    6
5    11
6    17
8    25
```

This is one solution I got:

```
select a.num, sum(b.num) from ID a, ID b where b.num <= a.num group by a.num order by a.num;
```

Comment: AFAIK, MySQL can't really do this sort of thing. `This` being referencing previous rows. You could use a temporary table, I suppose, but it might be better doing this sort of thing clientside.

Comment: Just a fun problem i got while playing with mysql. Trying to use joins.

Comment: You could certainly do it with variables, common someone will certainly show the @sum answer. I'm lazy.

Comment: I didn't want to do it with variables. Just sql query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured out the solution.

```
Select num as n, 
       (select sum(num) from ID where num <= n)
from ID order by n;
```

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work if you have duplicates, i.e. 1,2,3,3,4,5, you'll get 0,1,3,3,9,13, which I don't think is what you want.

Comment: Yup, that totally makes sense. I was looking at only unique values. Will update that in the question.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [temporary variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-user-variables.html) to calculate the cumulative sum:

```
SELECT  a.num,
   (@s := @s + a.num) AS cumulative
FROM ID a, (SELECT @s := 0) dm
ORDER BY a.num;
```

Comment: Anyone using the new MySql 8.0 should instead use [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)

Answer (score 1):

Since MySQL 8, cumulative sums are ideally calculated using [window functions](https://blog.jooq.org/2013/11/03/probably-the-coolest-sql-feature-window-functions/). In your case, run:

```
SELECT num, SUM(num) OVER (ORDER BY num) cumulative
FROM id
```

Comment: do u know why w/o order by it ouputs all sum not cumulative?

Comment: @Ambleu: Yes, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664436/cumulative-sum-over-a-set-of-rows-in-mysql/52373539?noredirect=1#comment109653718_52373539

Answer (score 0):

as these answer i already tested in my project and actually i want to know which one is faster so i also posted this here [which one is faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357516/subquery-or-leftjoin-with-group-by-which-one-is-faster/7454564#7454564)

```
declare @tmp table(ind int identity(1,1),col1 int)
insert into @tmp
select 2
union
select 4
union
select 7
union 

select 5
union
select 8
union 
select 10


 SELECT t1.col1,sum( t2.col1)
    FROM @tmp AS t1 LEFT JOIN @tmp t2 ON t1.ind>=t2.ind
    group by t1.ind,t1.col1

select t1.col1,(select sum(col1) from  @tmp as t2 where t2.ind<=t1.ind)
from @tmp as t1
```