# Creating a cumulative sum column

Tags: sql-server, sum

Sample table ID: (`num` is a key so there wouldn't be any duplicates)

```
num
1
5
6
8
2
3
```

**I need a query to make this:**
Desired output:
 (Should be sorted and have a cumulative sum column)

```
num cumulative
1    1
2    3
3    6
5    11
6    17
8    25
```

In **Mysql** I have

```
Select num as n, 
       (select sum(num) from ID where num <= n)
from ID order by n;
```

I picked up this example in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629200/creating-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql) but in MySqlServer

Comment: No, this column is simple value column @OlegDok

Comment: Then there will be no exact decision without proper identifying column

Comment: Table layout, please! And sum of what anyway?

Comment: You find a solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT num,(SELECT SUM(num) FROM tab WHERE num<=t.num) AS CumulativeSum
FROM tab t
```

Answer (score 0):

Since num is not unique, you may need to use row_number to get a unique number in there, then do the sum:

```
declare @t as table (num int)

insert into @t (num) values (1)
insert into @t (num) values (5)
insert into @t (num) values (6)
insert into @t (num) values (7)
insert into @t (num) values (2)
insert into @t (num) values (3)

;with rows as (
    select
        num,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by num) as Row
    from @t
)
select num, (select sum(num) from rows where row <= r.row)
from rows r
```