# Create a running subtotal for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get a running subtotal (understanding this is different from subtotals for groups, and the rollup approach).

Tried using

```
Row_Number() over (order by ID_Number) as Row_Count
```

and nesting it in select statements and using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on itself (which just churns).

What I am trying to get is this:

```
if ROW_COUNT > 1 THEN RUNNINGTOTAL = Volume_Category + (RUNNINGTOTAL for ID_Number where ROW_COUNT= ROW_COUNT(for this ID_Number*)-1)
```

I have a table with a list of unique "ID-Numbers" which are the focus here.

Comment: Can you provide simple data and result?

Comment: what version of sql server are you using?

Comment: There are a few questions on this, usually labeled cumulative sum.  I like the answers with temp variables, like this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7631964/931379.  They are usually much much faster than clever uses of the `sum` function.

Comment: @Pursuit the quirky update (things like `UPDATE SET @var = Total = @var + value`) is not guaranteed to process in any specific order, even if that's what you observe. Please see http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals for some details on this.

Comment: @pursuit I searched for answers before asking my own.  Needed to use 'cumulative' and not 'running subtotal'

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using SQL Server 2012, the easiest way to do a cumulative sum is with a correlated subquery.  Here is the template for the code:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(val) from t t2 where t2.ordercol <= t.ordercol) as cumesum
from t
```

In 2012, you can do:

```
select t.*,
       sum(val) over (order by ordercol) as cumesum
from t
```

In both these, `val` is the column you want to sum and `ordercol` is how the ordering is specified.

Comment: @bluefeet . . . LOL, I think you've made that suggestion before.  Will I ever learn?

Comment: I don't understand what is the second query!

Comment: @HamletHakobyan It's for SQL Server 2012!

Comment: @Lamak Are you sure is it returns cumulative sum? Can anyone give example on sql fiddle? Greate soltion!

Comment: Cursor actually wins out here at scale in my tests on < SQL 2012. And the SQL Server 2012 solution is pretty pitiful too unless you explicitly state `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` - by default this will use `RANGE`, which spools to disk automatically. http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals

Comment: I need to add filters so the first anser from Gordon Linoff works.  Thanks for the help.  I am a SQL newbie who last programmed in Pascal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   T1.Id,
   SUM(T2.Amount) Total
FROM tbl T1
   JOIN Tbl T2
      ON T1.Id>= T2.Id
GROUP BY T1.Id
```