# Cumulative sum over a set of rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, cumulative-sum

I have a complex query(containing multiple joins, unions) that returns a set of rows containing id, day, hr, amount. The output of the query looks like this:

```
id day    hr  amount 
1   1      1   10       
1   1      2   25       
1   1      3   30        
1   2      1   10       
1   2      2   40       
1   2      2   30        
2   1      1   10       
2   1      2   15        
2   1      3   30       
2   2      1   10       
2   2      2   20      
2   2      2   30
```

I need to find cumulative total for each id, for every hour of the day. The output should be like this:

```
id day    hr  amount cumulative total
1   1      1   10       10
1   1      2   25       35
1   1      3   30       65 
1   2      1   10       10
1   2      2   40       50
1   2      2   30       80 
2   1      1   10       10
2   1      2   15       25 
2   1      3   30       55
2   2      1   10       10
2   2      2   20       30
2   2      2   30       60
```

My initial query that produces the first output looks like this:

```
select id, day, hr, amount from
( //multiple joins on multiple tables)a
left join
(//unions on multiple tables)b
on a.id=b.id;
```

What's sql query to get the cumulative sum as described in the second output? SET should not be used in the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Before more convoluted (but possible) solutions: have you considered (a) if `WITH ROLLUP` is enough for your needs, and (b) how more easily this may be attainable in application code rather then SQL?

Comment: @Wrikken: a) WITH ROLLUP adds extra rows to the output, I need it in the form of a column, is it possible to achieve it using WITH ROLLUP? b) I agree that it will be simpler in the application code, but I'm faced with a situation where it has to be done in the SQL itself.

Comment: I would use a stored procedure that does something like this: 1. Create a temp table with the result of your query, 2. Add a column to the temp table, 3. Update each row of the temp table with the cumulative sum.

Comment: What you ask this way "I need to find cumulative total for each id, for every hour of the day" is NOT what the table displays. You have ID 1, DAY 2, HR 2 twice in your sample output. It doesn't seem to be possible to solve it that way without using variables, as you don't actually have a Primary Key to use in that table.

Comment: @MostyMostacho Corrected the output.

Comment: The answers provided for the "duplicate question" are insufficient; the queries in those answers will not produce the resultset specified in this question. (One big issue is that those queries do not produce a running total for each group, and reset it for the next group, as specified in this question. Those queries only produce a running total for the entire set. This is significantly different question.

Answer (score 13):

*UPDATE*

MySQL 8.0 introduces "window functions", functionality equivalent to SQL Server "window functions" (with partitioning and ordering provided by Transact-SQL `OVER` syntax), and Oracle "analytic functions". It also now supports CTEs.

MySQL Reference Manual 12.21 Window Functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html

The answer provided here is an approach for MySQL versions prior to 8.0.

---

*ORIGINAL ANSWER*

MySQL doesn't provide the type analytic function you would use to get a running "cumulative sum", like the analytic functions available in other DBMS (like Oracle or SQL Server.)

But, it is possible to emulate some analytic functions, using MySQL.

There are (at least) two workable approaches:

One is to use a correlated subquery to get the subtotal. This approach can be expensive on large sets, and complicated if the predicates on the outer query are complicated. It really depends on how complicated that "multiple joins on multiple tables" is. (Unfortunately, MySQL also does not not support CTEs either.)

The other approach is to make use of MySQL user variables, to do some control break processing. The "trick" here is to the results from your query sorted (using an ORDER BY) and then wrapping your query in another query.

I'll give an example of the latter approach.

Because of the order that MySQL performs operations, the `cumulative_total` column needs to be computed before the value from `id` and `day` from the current row are saved into user variables. It's just easiest to put this column first.

The inline view aliased as i (in the query below) is just there to initialize the user variables, just in case these are already set in the session. If those already have values assigned, we want to ignore their current values, and the easiest way to do that is to initialize them.

Your original query gets wrapped in parenthesis, and is given an alias, `c` in the example below. The only change to your original query is the addition of an ORDER BY clause, so we can be sure that we process the rows from the query in sequence.

The outer select checks whether the `id` and `day` value from the current row "match" the previous row. If they do, we add the `amount` from the current row to the cumulative subtotal. If they don't match, then we reset the the cumulative subtotal to zero, and add the amount from the current row  (or, more simply, just assign the amount from the current row).

After we have done the computation of the cumulative total, we save the `id` and `day` values from the current row into user variables, so they are available when we process the next row.

For example:

```
SELECT IF(@prev_id = c.id AND @prev_day = c.day
         ,@cumtotal := @cumtotal + c.amount
         ,@cumtotal := c.amount) AS cumulative_total
     , @prev_id  := c.id  AS `id`
     , @prev_day := c.day AS `day`
     , c.hr
     , c.amount AS `amount'
  FROM ( SELECT @prev_id  := NULL
              , @prev_day := NULL
              , @subtotal := 0
       ) i
  JOIN (

         select id, day, hr, amount from
         ( //multiple joins on multiple tables)a
         left join
         (//unions on multiple tables)b
         on a.id=b.id

         ORDER BY 1,2,3
       ) c
```

If it's necessary to return the columns in a different order, with cumulative total as the last column, then one option is to wrap that whole statement in a set of parens, and use that query as an inline view:

```
SELECT d.id
     , d.day
     , d.hr
     , d.amount
     , d.cumulative_total
FROM (
       // query from above
     ) d
```

Comment: you can write a simple query... look at the answer below, it is a simply query that does the trick.

Comment: In the simple query, the OP original query would need to be specified twice, in place of "foo". (If any change is made to the original query, it will need to be modified in two places.) The output from the simple query does not meet the specification, at least in the case of the fifth row in the OP example, since there are two rows `id=1 day=2 hr=2`. According to the spec, the subtotal of the fifth row should not include the amount from the sixth row.

Comment: N.B. The answers provided in the question that was marked as a "duplicate" will not produce the resultset you specified. Those will produce a running total for the entire set, and not for each group. Those queries also do not handle the duplicate instances of the grouping key.

Comment: This approach is very fast as well. I've had some trouble to get a cumulative sum on about 15 columns in a couple of milion rows. I've tried many different approaches. The solution from @lukas-eder is nice, but it will take longer and longer if the number of rows (to sum) is increasing. This solution from @spencer7593 doesn't really care how large your set is and it will stay fast.

`25000 rows in 0.19 sec` vs `4.43 sec`

Answer (score 7):

If you're on MySQL 8 or later, you should use [window functions](https://blog.jooq.org/2013/11/03/probably-the-coolest-sql-feature-window-functions/) for this. Your query would read:

```
SELECT
  id, day, hr, amount,
  SUM (amount) OVER (PARTITION BY id, day ORDER BY hr) AS `cumulative total`
FROM t
```

Where `t` is your table `b` left joined to `a`. Some notes:

- The `PARTITION BY` clause guarantees that you get a cumulative sum per `id` and `day`, so each day, we start summing afresh
- The `ORDER BY` clause defines by what ordering the cumulation should happen

Comment: It is really nice to see more and more RDBMSes support such constructs. Next big thing I would like to be implemented is [MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53994970/5070879) - btw. your blog is really great([10 SQL Tricks That You Didn’t Think Were Possible](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/04/25/10-sql-tricks-that-you-didnt-think-were-possible/) inspired me :)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda: Thanks for your nice words. I'm not sure if `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` will be a priority on MySQL anytime soon, but you never know!

Comment: how come we don't get cumulative some if we don't add order by clause? even though I don't give order shouldn't it add each row to new sum?

Comment: @Ambleu: If you use `ORDER BY`, then `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` is implicit (cumulative sum semantics). If you don't use `ORDER BY`, then `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` is implicit (aggregation of entire partition semantics). This is actually quite a useful default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

here you go, here is your culminative total...

```
select f1.id, f1.day, f1.hr, f1.amount, sum(f2.amount) as culminative_total from foo f1
 inner join foo f2 on (f1.day = f2.day and f1.id=f2.id)
 where f2.hr <= f1.hr
 group by f1.id, f1.day, f1.hour;
```

Comment: This does not return the specified resultset if there are duplicates of `(id, day, hr)`, as in the fifth and sixth rows in the OP example. In the OP case, foo is not a simple table, but rather a query that involves multiple tables. This query will need to be specified twice (in place of foo), which means MySQL will materialize that query twice. Unfortunately, MySQL does not yet support Common Table Expressions (CTE) which would be one way to avoid duplicating the subquery.

Comment: very sharp indeed :) didn't noticed that detail in the initial data

Comment: If we did have a guarantee of uniqueness (on the columns we need for the join), then the semi-join approach used by the query in this answer would return the specified result.

Comment: yeah, I know. I didn't noticed the duplicates when I did my initial inspection of the problem...