# Grouping users - cumulative count by month

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, grouping

I can group users by count in each month like this:

```
User.group('year(created_at)').group('month(created_at)').count
#=> {[2015, 4]=>90, [2015, 5]=>133, [2015, 6]=>131, [2015, 7]=>28, [2015, 8]=>45, [2015, 9]=>6}
```

I want to create stats, showing how users count was growing by months.

So it would return something like this:

```
{[2015, 4]=>20, [2015, 5]=>40, [2015, 6]=>55, [2015, 7]=>70, [2015, 8]=>100, [2015, 9]=>130}
# each entry is a year, month and total users count from the beginning of time by the end of this month.
```

How would I get the wanted result?

I am looking for a database level solution (ActiveRecord query) if possible.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Please edit to explain how `[2015,4]=>20` and `[2015,5]=>40` were computed. It would also be helpful to assign a variable to the input hash (e.g., `h = User.group(....`), so that those giving answers can refer to the variable without having to define it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland As I mentioned in the comment of desired output, the `[2015,4]=>20` means that in 4th month of year 2015 (the beginning of the application existence) 20 users registered in the application, `[2015,5]=>40` means, that from the beginning of times (4th month 2015) until end of 5th month 40 users registered, `[2015, 6]=>55` means, that from beginning of times unitl end of 6th month of 2015 55 users registered and so on, so that i have exponential statistics of users count in the application by months.

Comment: Andrey, that's what I figured (cumulative users by month), but I don't know where the values of the desired output come from. For example, how did you get `20` from `90`? Also, I don't know what you mean by "exponential" in the title or why all the values in the desired output are multiples of `5` (if not coincidence).

Comment: The collection to operate on is `User::ActiveRecord_Relation`. I am afraid I can't provide you with the entire collection. Edited the title with cumulative (the word I was looking for, thanks!) regarding multiples of `5` - coincidence :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664436/cumulative-sum-over-a-set-of-rows-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

So, correct me if I misunderstood anything. You have user registrations by months, i.e. 1 user in Jan, 2 users in Feb and 3 in March and you want to build a chart with user growth, so you want 1 user in Jan, 3 users in Feb and 6 in March.
If that's the case, you can do the following:

```
counts = {[2015, 4]=>1, [2015, 5]=>2, [2015, 6]=>3, [2015, 7]=>4, [2015, 8]=>5, [2015, 9]=>6}     

keys = counts.keys # save keys => [[2015, 4], [2015, 5], [2015, 6], [2015, 7], [2015, 8], [2015, 9]]

acc_values = counts.values.dup # .dup is needed if you don't want to spoil original values  
# because of for the following map! operation, 
# right now acc_values returns => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

# use map! instead of map so we have access to already changed items, 
# while we iterating over the next
acc_values.map!.with_index { |val, key| key.zero? ? val : acc_values[key - 1] + val }    
# => [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21]

# build resulting hash
acc_counts = keys.zip(acc_values).to_h    
# => {[2015, 4]=>1, [2015, 5]=>3, [2015, 6]=>6, [2015, 7]=>10, [2015, 8]=>15, [2015, 9]=>21}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case - I don't have counts, I am aiming to get those. Please, read the discussion under my question, it could be helpful in clarifying what I need.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Oh, it seems you need the backwards operation, right? So, you have 1 in Jan, 3 in Feb, and 6 in March and you want them back to 1, 2, 3?

Comment: You can use your code `User.group('year(created_at)').group('month(created_at)').count` to get raw counts by months, and them my code to convert them to cumulative counts. If you want a complete SQL solution you'll have to resort to using variables which can lead to a quite ugly solution, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664436/cumulative-sum-over-a-set-of-rows-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

If `g` is a given hash where `g[[y,m]]` is the number of new users in year `y`, month `m` and you want to create a hash `h` for which `h[[y,m]]` is the cumulative number of users in year `y`, month `m`, rounded to the nearest `5`, `h` can be computed as follows:

```
g = {[2015, 4]=>90, [2015, 5]=>133, [2015, 6]=>131, [2015, 7]=>28,
     [2015, 8]=>45, [2015, 9]=>6}

h = g.keys.sort.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|k,h| h[k]=g[k]+ h[previous(k)]}
  #=> {[2015, 4]=>90, [2015, 5]=>223, [2015, 6]=>354, [2015, 7]=>382,
  #    [2015, 8]=>427, [2015, 9]=>433} 
h.update(h) { |_,v| round_to_nearest(v, 5) }
  #=> {[2015, 4]=>90, [2015, 5]=>225, [2015, 6]=>355, [2015, 7]=>380,
  # [2015, 8]=>425, [2015, 9]=>435} 

 def previous((year, month))
  month -= 1
  (year -=1; month = 12) if month.zero?
  [year, month]
end

def round_to_nearest(n, d)
  d*(n/d.to_f).round
end
```

Please let me know if I've misunderstood the question (e.g., perhaps you intended to do this in the database). If so, I'll amend or delete my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot! you've got the idea right, but the issue is that I can't define methods here. And yeah, I was planning to do it on the database level  (ActiveRecord query).

Comment: Could this be translated to an `ActiveRecord` query? If so, consider adding an answer yourself. (I'm not familiar with `ActiveRecord`.)