# Calculating a complex cumulative value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

The relevant tables and attempted solution have been listed at the bottom of this post. The goal and the problem are described immediately below.

**The Goal**

The goal of this query is to build the PHP array of objects (returned rows) below. This is a timestamped history of every transaction made for each currency pair filtered by user. I am able to achieve everything except for the `cumulative_quantity` values

```
'BTC-USD' => array(
  array(
    'timestamp' => (int),
    'price' => (float),
    'price_usd' => (float),
    'buy_sell' => (bool),
    'quantity' => (float),
    'total_value' => (float),
    'total_value_usd' => (float),
    'cumulative_quantity' => (float),
    'cumulative_quantity_base' => (float)
  )
)
```

**The Problem**

Calculating the cumulative quantity for each user's row in `pf_items` requires also checking whether the `buy_sell` field is 0 (sell) or 1 (buy) and adding/subtracting accordingly.

It is made slightly more complex as `cumulative_quantity_base` requires that the `quantity` values for BTC-USD and (for instance) BTC-EUR are merged under a simple BTC array of objects. For instance, if a row in `pf_items` relating to BTC-USD (`base_currency` and `quote_currency`) had a buy quantity of 5, and another row relating to BTC-EUR had a buy quantity of 7, it would need to find the cumulative value for BTC of these two rows: 12.

**pf_currencies**

```
CREATE TABLE `pf_currencies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `symbol` varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

**pf_currencies_history**

```
CREATE TABLE `pf_currencies_history` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `base_currency` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quote_currency` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` float NOT NULL,
  `date_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

**pf_portfolios**

```
CREATE TABLE `pf_portfolios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**pf_items**

```
CREATE TABLE `pf_items` (
  `id` int(11),
  `portfolio_id` int(11),
  `action_date` date,
  `price` float,
  `price_usd` float,
  `buy_sell` tinyint(1),
  `quantity` float,
  `base_currency` int(11),
  `quote_currency` int(11),
  `date_added` datetime
)
```

**My Query**
This query achieves what is needed except for `cumulative_quantity` and `cumulative_quantity_base` as described.

```
SELECT (SELECT
         symbol
       FROM pf_currencies
       WHERE a.base_currency = id)
       AS base_currency,
       (SELECT
         symbol
       FROM pf_currencies
       WHERE a.quote_currency = id)
       AS quote_currency,
       a.price,
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.date_time) AS unix_time
FROM pf_currencies_history a
INNER JOIN pf_items i
  ON i.portfolio_id = (SELECT
    id
  FROM pf_portfolios
  WHERE user_id = ".$userId.")
  AND a.base_currency = i.base_currency
  AND a.quote_currency = i.quote_currency
ORDER BY unix_time DESC
```

Comment: STR_TO_DATE(a.date_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') - erm, what does this do?

Comment: Converts my date string YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00 into a unix timestamp

Comment: No. UNIX_TIMESTAMP does that.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @Strawberry, that conversion is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, have edited and updated the query above.

Comment: The cumulative quantity is simple, there are dozens of questions around how to calculate running totals / cumulative sums with conditions here on SO. You really should search and make an honest attempt. However, I do not get the cumulative quantity base definition. Can you pls illustrate with sample data and expected output what you want to achieve there?

Comment: As I wrote, that conversion is totally unnecessary. The `date_time` field has datetime data time, not string, so there is no need to convert it from string to date and then to unix datetime.

Comment: @Shadow running totals are fine, but it also needs to do a statement based around the (bool) `buy_sell`. I appreciate the suggestion to Google the problem, however that is a route I have already exhausted. Any help would be appreciated and I will update the question to include more info around base.

Comment: As I wrote, you need to check questions discussing cumulative sums with conditions, such as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664436/cumulative-sum-over-a-set-of-rows-in-mysql

Comment: A question - your inner join between pf_items and pf_currencies_history depends on not having two records in pf_currencies_history with the same base_currency and quote_currency (and also on not having problems with comparing integers to strings).  Is that intentional?

Comment: @Koen `base_currency` and `quote_currency` should be int (11) - my mistake. The inner join is on portfolio_id, purely so I can get all the history from that user's portfolio, the join is intentional. I may be misunderstanding the point you're getting at though.