# sql grouping of calculation

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, case

Does anyone have a solution how to group sums of two categories with case statements?

In the below screenshot i would like to merge two rows to one and just display PE and NPE sums in the columns flag1total and flag2total, but it's not working.

This is the SQL I have at the moment:

```
select type, flag, coalesce(sum(value),0) total,
case when flag = "NPE" then coalesce(sum(value),0) else "" end as flag1total,
case when flag = "PE" then coalesce(sum(value),0) else "" end as flag2total
from maintable
group by type, flag;
```

[image: screenshot]

The data looks like this

```
 type     flag          value
 P_OTH    PE            23525
 P_OTH    PE            13525
 P_CRE    PE            232525
 P_OTH    PE            4525
 ....
```

The expected result is this (one line per type and vectorized sums for the flags):

```
 type     flag          total      flag1total   flag2total
 P_OTH    PE, NPE       3023624    1132707      1890917
```

Comment: Update your question and add  also the expcted  result  (and data sample) as tabular text  ..(not image)

Comment: Sorry this is unclear to me. You want the total for PE, total for NPE and the sum of the total NPE and total PE ?

Comment: updated the questions... i just want flag1total and flag2total... the general sum is there just to illustrate

Comment: I think you'll find happiness there :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664436/cumulative-sum-over-a-set-of-rows-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use case inside your sum function. Try something like this:

```
select type, coalesce(sum(value),0) total,
    coalesce(sum(case when flag = "NPE" then value else 0 end),0)   as flag1total,
    coalesce(sum(case when flag = "PE" then value else 0 end),0)  as flag2total
 from maintable
 group by type;
```

Note that 'flag' can't be in group by clause.

Comment: just to be sure, this only applies when grouping, otherwise i can use my old query using case outside of my function?

Comment: @GabrielCandido . . . The `coalesce()` is unnecessary.

Comment: @dfhdfh yes, it's not wrong to use it outside, depends on how do you want the result to be.

Comment: @GordonLinoff true, didn't think through it. thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need below -

```
SELECT  type
       ,GROUP_CONCAT(flag, ', ') flag
       ,coalesce(sum(value),0) total
       ,coalesce(sum(case when flag = "NPE" then value else 0 end),0)   as flag1total
       ,coalesce(sum(case when flag = "PE" then value else 0 end),0)  as flag2total
 from maintable
 group by type;
```