# What is the best method to search for string from one table in another

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, table1 and table2. I need to search occurrence of table1.col1 in col1.table2. How can I achieve this ?

I did the following statement, but I'm not experienced in mySQL. I'm not sure if this the right method to query from two different unrelated tables? col1 and col2 are strings.

```
select table1.col1, table2.col1 from table1, table2 where 
STRCMP(table1.col1, table2.col1)=0;
```

Is this correct statement for my purpose? Can it be optimized ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "best way" is to join both tables.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    table1 a 
            INNER JOIN table2 b
                ON a.col1 = b.col1
-- WHERE   --other condition here
```

SubQuery Method (*but I'll prefer on joining tables*)

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table1
WHERE   col1 IN
   (
     SELECT col1 
     FROM   table2
     -- WHERE -- condition here  
   )
```

Comment: another way is by using subquery, although it is slower than join. I'll update my answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357516/subquery-or-leftjoin-with-group-by-which-one-is-faster

Comment: @John Woo: What do yoou mean by WHER--condition here?? What I want to do is search for table1.col1 occurrence in table2.col1 .. Do I need any conditions ?? Or IN is enough to do the purpose ?

Comment: i mean if you have any "extra" filtering condition :) but if not, you can just omit it.

Answer (score 0):

As John said Joins would be better :), but you could always put another SELECT statement in the WHERE clause